# Якорь на сайте (главная страница)

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать якорь.
На сайте в меню есть кнопка "товары", при нажатии на нее, должно спускаться страница чуть ниже до блока "товары", как сделать?
сайт https://www.gls-trade.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, какое отношение вопрос имеет к Вордпрессу, если это обычный html?

В тексте, куда необходимо перейти по ссылке, например, в параграфе, разместите якорь:

```
<p>Какой-то текст в котором мы поместим <span id="products">якорь</span>.</p>
```

А в меню разместите ссылку вида:

```
<a href="#products">Товары</a>
```

Если вы не знаете как подобное реализовать в меню средствами wordpress - это уже другое дело.

А можно атрибут id указать целому параграфу, так может ещё и лучше будет.

```
<p id="products">Какой-то абзац, который целиком является якорем.</p>
```

Так лучше ещё и с той точки зрения, что элемент `span` может у вас иметь какое-то особое оформление, и обойтись без него будет правильнее.

Comment: оо, супер
все работает0

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Если ответ помог, можете нажать на галочку под ним. А ещё смените тэг на html. wordpress - не при чём.

Comment: Атрибут `name` для элемента `<a>` вышел из употребления в HTML5 и считается устаревшим. Якорем может быть любой элемент с атрибутом `id`.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, вы правы, так ещё лучше. Исправлю в своём ответе. Спасибо, что напомнили. Использую крайне редко ))